# How to fix error CS0246 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#

I'm following Michiel Wouters' snake game tutorial on youtube, and "Keys" enum does not work

This message always comes up: "The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I made shure System.Windows.Forms was referenced, and added System.Windows.Forms.dll to the project folder

this is my input class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Snake
{
    class Input
    {


        //Load list  of available Keyboard buttons
        private static Hashtable keyTable = new Hashtable();

        //Perform a check to see if a particular button is pressed
        public static bool KeyPressed(Keys key)
        {
            if (keyTable[key] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (bool)keyTable[key];
        }
        //Detect if a keyboard button is pressed
        public static void ChangeState(Keys key, bool state)
        {
            keyTable[key] = state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. A few questions for you, 1) Can you give us the exact error message reported by the compiler as well as indicate where in the code the compiler points to from that error message? 2) Could you make sure there aren't any other problems with your code, such as the incomplete KeyPressed method (missing parameter name and method body)? If you have incomplete code the compiler might not fully understand the relevance of a particular word and might mistake it or its usage for something else, I just want to eliminate that the incomplete method is the reason.

Comment: You didn't write the full function `KeyPressed` I think

Comment: Also you forgot `using System.Windows.Forms;`.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Look at the tutorial again. You forgot to add a `using` statement,
which was explicitly mentioned there:

[image]

(Sorry for the picture, but the original site has no copyable text also)

Answer (score 0):

Missing Keys class. Add the new Keys class and it should compile